# Can I host a mc server on my web server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a website and I want to host a mc server on it.

I already made a subdomain and my host is Dreamhost.

It does not have shared hosting.

Comment: Are you asking us if you're *allowed* to host a web server?  Or how *to* host one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dedicated root server to be able to install arbitary software and use up all those system resources. You can´t do that on shared servers, websites etc.
If you are not sure f you have a dedicated root server, you don't. (They usually start at 50 USD / Month)

Comment: Well, to be fair, you _can_ in theory do both on a cheap VPS (I have in the past), it just will run like absolute crap.

Comment: @aman207 depending on what you use it for. I run a 1GB ram/ 1.4 GHz Intel pentium mine craft server just for exploring a interesting seed, and it works without question. Although, that probably Isn't the use OP intends, so it won't work for him.